# Python3, read specific word from .txt file

Tags: python-3.x

I want to know how I can search for a specific word in a .txt file using Python3.
If the word 'pizza' is included in the .txt file, then it should (e.g.) import another python program.

Comment: And what do your research efforts suggest you should use?

Comment: I found nothing similiar

Comment: I belive you can find the answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27914129/8362224

Comment: And if that doesn't help, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49335342/edit) your question and add code that you tried, and why it didn't do what you wanted. See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through each line in the file with a 'for' loop and check to see if the string is in the line:

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
   if 'pizza' in line:
      # do whatever you want here
      print("Found it!")
   else: 
      pass
```