# Methods for Point of View Analysis using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, nlp, text-analysis

Can anyone please point me to some techniques to do a **Point of View Analysis** on novel text?

I'm basically looking for methods to determine how many words were written from different characters Points of View in any novel preferably using **Python**

Something like this: [Statistical Analysis of WoT](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/The_Eye_of_the_World/Statistical_analysis)

Comment: What will be the application of thoses techniques ? Could be useful for us to know, would be easier to help you

Comment: For doing a statistical analysis on a novel. Mainly to know how diverse is a novel in terms of Race, religion etc.
Very similar to this: https://www.barnesandnoble.com/blog/sci-fi-fantasy/statistical-analysis-wheel-time/.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27914069/how-to-find-words-in-text-files-with-python) could help you.

You first start by storing every word, then you count every apparition.

If you also need to plot them in a graph, you should try to do an histogram with matplotlib like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328556/histogram-matplotlib).

Hope it helps !

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get that. How would I be able to know which character is speaking a string of words with that method?

Comment: How is delimited a character speach ? How is it opened and close ? Can you show us a little exemple of 2 characters speaking ?

Comment: Vin was so stunned that she nearly collided with him. She stumbled, slowing herself maladroitly, as if she had forgotten how to do anything other than run. 
This is wrong, she thought. I can’t just stand here. I have to be moving.

She felt herself begin to move again, but Kelsier grabbed her. She struggled in his grip, resisting weakly.

Rest, something within her said. Relax. You’ve forgotten what that is, but it’s so nice
“Vin!” Kelsier said. “Don’t extinguish your pewter. Keep burning it or you’ll fall unconscious!”
“Tin!” he said. “Flare it. Now!”

Comment: That's a small text from the book

Comment: I couldn't get anywhere in terms of PoV analysis. I did the basic stuff of text cleaning and splitting it into words and getting a word count for each word etc. but I'm stuck after that. And I saw that it's possible, because some other sites have such analysis and I'm looking for leads on that